# Problem right after creating a React project with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs

I have suddenly started having a problem which I didn't have before.

I do the following steps:

> ```
> mkdir someapp
> cd someapp
> npx create-react-app .
> ```

Till this stage everything is fine. My next command to start the app is:

> ```
> npm start
> ```

The react app opens normally in the browser.

However, when I check the console, I see the following three errors showing:

GET chrome-extension://gomekmidlodglbbmalcneegieacbdmki/locales/Locale-en-US.json net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Access to fetch at 'https://s-install.avcdn.net/aos/assets/prod/translations/Locale-en-US.json' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

GET https://s-install.avcdn.net/aos/assets/prod/translations/Locale-en-US.json net::ERR_FAILED 404

I reiterate that I have nothing installed other than the vanilla react app.

Can someone please help and advise how I clear these errors. The app I develop runs fine but I am afraid when this might explode into a bigger problem later.

Thanks,
Teejay

Comment: You url clearly shows that it's loading a file which is part of an extension. No need to worry about it. It's not your react code. It's some extension that you are using.

Comment: Thank you for responding Pranava. However, I have not used any extension at all. Just plain creation of react app and running it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ok. I got it. I disabled all the chrome extensions and found that the problem was gone. I then enabled them one by one and found that extension "Avast Online Security & Privacy" was the culprit. Keeping it disabled didn't give the errors mentioned in my question. Now what will happen if I keep this chrome extension disabled is a question of another day.

Many thanks.